# Returning a reference to istream in C++

Tags: c++, reference, istream

I read this on Accelerated C++. Here is a simplified version.

```
istream& read_hw(istream& in, Student_info& s)
{    
    in >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;
    return in;
}
```

Then, we can call the function as:

```
Student_info s;
read_hw(cin, s);
```

My question is,

1. What's the point of returning the reference to istream? Since both the two parameters are passed by reference;
2. While calling the function, we don't seem to care about the returning value

Comment: Here is a [great site](http://augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/iotips.html) on C++/IO. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read the next paragraph:

> Returning the stream allows our caller to write
>
> ```
> if (read_hw(cin, homework)){/*...*/}
> ```
>
> as an abbreviation for
>
> ```
> read_hw(cin, homework);
> if (cin) {/*...*/}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Returning the reference to `istream` enables cascading. For example:

```
int i, j;
std::cin >> i >> j;
// Equivalent to std::cin.operator>>(i).operator>>(j);
```

`istream::operator>>()` returns `istream&` so that the cascaded `>>` works.

Comment: If it was operator>> it would.... Well, you stil can but the syntax isn't so nice